# Installing python 3.5 on Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: python, linux

I am very new to linux and want to use python as it is the language I am learning at school. I have looked online and checked my current version is 2.7 which is no good to me as I am learning python 3. However, I have heard that changing your systems python version can be very bad so I don't know what to do :(. Also, is there a way to use it like you can in windows such as opening the IDLE and opening a new shell to write your code in there, because all I can find on the internet is how to write code in python through the terminal which I do not want to do.

Thanks.

Comment: You may already have it installed if you run `python3` in the terminal.

Comment: python3 is already on your system, yes changing your default system python can be catastrophic but there is a big difference between having another version installed and changing the system default

Comment: StackOverflow should really enforce writing helpful comments when downvoting a question or answer. It looks really bad when the top hit in a websearch leads to a question with a negative score and a perfectly good answer.

Answer (score 5):

The default python3 in Mint17.3 is python3.4,  and you can use ppa:fkrull to install python3.5.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update; 
sudo apt-get install python3.5
```

Comment: Does this replace 3.4 or install 3.5 parallel to 3.4?

Comment: The python executable will be installed to usr/bin (parallel). Check this folder to see what you have to type in the terminal. For example `python3.6` here. Tested on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can install as many Python versions as you wish, that won't do anything bad for your OS. But changing *the default Python interpreter* may be not so good.

Secondly, you can use any IDE (such as [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)) for coding or just use your favorite text editor and just run `python your_file.py` in the terminal.