# Install program from .deb file, using incorrect python version

Tags: python, linux, deb, linux-mint

I'm trying to install a program from a .deb file on Linux mint, but getting an error at installation as the program requires python >=3.5 (I have 3.4.0 as default). I've installed 3.6.0 but the defualt version appears first in the path (I don't think I want to change this?) so installation still fails.

I've tried to change the local python to 3.6.0 using pyenv, but it still only recognises the default 3.4.0 version. Any ideas what to try?

Comment: The order of the path shouldn't normally matter when installing things, because Linux will only check that the dependency is fulfilled. Python3.6 however is quite new and might not even be defined in the package as a viable version range? There for it defaults back to any other installed Python versions and that would be 3.4 in your case. Consider just following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372731/installing-python-3-5-on-linux-mint-17-3

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ppa:fkrull` to `install python3.5.`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update; 
sudo apt-get install python3.5
```

It surely helps to others

> Help:If you want to install python3.6 see this link [python3.6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've tried this, and now have 3.5.2 installed, however the program still fails to install saying python3 version on system is 3.4.0

Comment: kk wait i will give you the solution

Comment: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-ont-albacore:
 python3-ont-albacore depends on python3 (>= 3.5~); however:
  Version of python3 on system is 3.4.0-0ubuntu2.